# Adding and removing legends with layer selection in Leaflet

Tags: layers, legend, leaflet

I'm new to Leaflet/Javascript and have been struggling to get legends a map to show only when a specific layer is selected from the layer control. I have three layers, one of which I would like to have no legend and two others that have a corresponding legend. I came across an example, but have not been able to make it work:

```
// Add and remove legend from layers
map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
// Switch to the Permafrost legend...
   if (eventLayer.name === 'Permafrost') {
       this.removeControl(legend1);
       legend2.addTo(this);}
  else { // Or switch to the treeline legend...
       this.removeControl(legend2);
       legend1.addTo(this);
  }});
```

I created a jsfiddle with the specific example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gerlis/T8DHb/3/

Comment: Please explain more specifically *how* your example fails to work.

Comment: The example I have on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gerlis/T8DHb/3/) has the default view on a layer called "Satellite" and has the two legends showing. What I would like to do is have an action to add and remove specific legends when you select the layers from the Layer Control . On the specific example I want my "Satellite" layer to contain no legend, and when I select "Permafrost" I want only legend2 to show map, and when I select "Treeline", I want only legend1 to show on the map. The current code does not do any of the above and has both legends on all layers.

Answer (score 5):

You've defined your layers as baselayers (not overlays) and so you'll want to change `overlayadd` to `baselayerchange`

```
map.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
```

should be

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function (eventLayer) {
```

Here's a fork of your original jsFiddle that demonstrates this change - 
http://jsfiddle.net/ry9zf/2/